# Jail time in Dragonsearch Dungeon (Whiterun) in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did some silly things in Whiterun such as trying to kill the Jarl :D So, they arrested me once, I can escape but can't find my items, so instead I want to serve my sentence somehow. Although I'm been sleeping for about 100 hours, no one comes. So, what should I do now?

Comment: If you try to escape, I believe you cannot change your mind and then sleep. Full commitment to either task is the only way to complete it.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are currently incarcerated I believe just clicking the bed and sleeping for any amount of time should end your sentence, so if you are sleeping a lot and nothing is happening you sir have a bug.

If you have the capability to escape I would do so and check all the chests in the room where the guards hang out and sit around (not the exit into dragonsreach but the exit just into whiterun).  There are multiple chests in this room (2 or 3 I think) and that's where your stuff will be.  Hope this helped.